# Is ist possible to get the columns of a table base dVAR in DAX-functions?

Tags: powerbi, var

Is there a possiblity to get the columns of a calculated variable in Power BI?

How can i use MAX with the calculated table var
(i know that it is possible to calcuate it with a calculated table in the model or in different ways - the question is, is it possible to get columns of a table VAR.

While this works:

```
HighestOrderQuantity = 
VAR ORDERS=SUMMARIZECOLUMNS(Sales[ordernumber],"OrderQuantity",sum(sales[quantity]))
RETURN COUNTROWS(ORDERS)
```

this does not work:

```
HighestOrderQuantity = 
VAR ORDERS=SUMMARIZECOLUMNS(Sales[ordernumber],"OrderQuantity",sum(sales[quantity]))
RETURN MAX(ORDERS[OrderQuantity]))
```

Answer (score 0):

For this type of calculation you need to use `MAXX` instead of `MAX`. The basic aggregator functions, such as `MAX`, `MIN`, `SUM` etc. can only be used on tables that exist in the data model.

However, the iterator functions, such as `MAXX`, `MINX` and `SUMX` are the base functions for those basic aggregators. In fact, these two measures are identical:

```
Max_Basic = MAX ( 'Table'[Column] )
```

```
Max_Iterator = MAXX ( 'Table', 'Table'[Column] )
```

The base measure is actually translated to the more advanced expression by the engine under the hood. The basic functions are *syntax sugar*.

The iterator functions can be used with temporary tables. This DAX would do what you are after:

```
HighestOrderQuantity =
VAR _orders =
    SUMMARIZECOLUMNS (
        Sales[ordernumber],
        "OrderQuantity", SUM ( sales[quantity] )
    )
RETURN
    MAXX ( _orders, [OrderQuantity] )
```